# Enforce a particular check-in comment syntax

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, tfs, .net-4.5

I have made check-in comments mandatory in Team Foundation Server 2012. Now I need to enforce each check-in comment is in this format:

> [JIRA-1234] testing TFS checkins

1. Left square bracket
2. JIRA ticket number (a plus if this ticket number can be validated)
3. Right square bracket
4. A string briefly describing the change.

Is creating a custom check-in policy the only way to achieve this or is their an alternative? Custom check-in policies are client-side. is there a server-side solution?

Comment: I guess this will be downvoted, but still, cannot help it... "Don't use Team Foundation Server" in the first place...? ;)

Comment: why not migrate the Jira stories to TFS tasks and skip the need to refer to their IDs? TFS can enforce the check-ins to have a task attached, why use clunky Jira?

Comment: Sten, because JIRA is being used company-wide.

Comment: @Per Lundberg I have had huge success using TFS for many years, and whilst it is not perfect, I have found it to be incredibly powerful and good at doing what it does. If you have problems with it feel free to elaborate as to why, or perhaps ask for help on this forum. Otherwise, unsupported comments like "don't use it", directed at someone who clearly is using it, are unhelpful to say the least.

Comment: @bornfromanegg A 4-year old comment, and written a bit tongue-in-cheek. If TFS works well for you, go for it. Personally I find the distributed systems (where git is king) to be superior in all important aspects. Offline operations, powerful stashing, cheap branching & merging, being able to rebase & squash commits: all these are features that would make my work more awkward if I didn't have them.

Comment: @Per Lundberg Yes, I do understand, and I know it's an old comment. Maybe I should have just left it. I just wouldn't want any visitor here, who didn't know anything about TFS, to get the impression that it shouldn't be used. Git and TFS are both excellent choices, depending on what you need.

Answer (score 2):

You could create an ISubscriber plug-in that gets deployed to the TFS Server and runs server-side.  ISubscriber plug-ins can subscribe to TFS Events (such as Check-In) and have custom code to respond appropriately.

Unfortunately, it doesn't give the opportunity to prevent the check-in, but you could send a notification to a dev lead/manager, or automatically roll-back the check-in.

More info on writing an ISubscriber here: http://nakedalm.com/team-foundation-server-2010-event-handling-with-subscribers/